# Completely uninstall openldap from Redhat Linux server

Tags: linux, openldap

I have performed the following steps to install OpenLdap on my Redhat Linux Server:

```
    1. untar the tar file
    2. ./configure <--this ran successfully without error
    3. make depend
    4. make
    5. make test <-- couldn't find any error
    6. make install
    7. started slapd: /usr/local/sbin/slapd
```

But the service is not starting. I don't see any slapd process in the `ps -lef | grep slapd` output. Also I see this, when i run : `ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base '(objectclass=*)' namingContexts`

```
    ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

What could be the error and also How can I completely uninstall `OPENLDAP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions here:

1. What could be the error?

   It's possible that you haven't appropriately configured `slapd`.  There are probably errors in your syslog (`/var/log/messages`) that will help you diagnose problems.  You can also run `slapd` in debugging mode (`slapd -d none`) to see errors displayed on your terminal.
2. How can I completely uninstall OpenLDAP?

   That's a little tricky, since you (a) elected to install it from source rather than using an existing package and (b) you didn't install it into a dedicated directory.  To *completely* uninstall it, you would have to pay close attention to what files are installed by running `make install` and then remove them.

   However, there's no harm in leaving the files installed on your system as long as you're not using them.  You can remove anything that was installed into `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/sbin` if you want to prevent them from conflicting with versions of those commands installed via system packages.

   If OpenLDAP is the only thing you've installed in `/usr/local` you can just remove any files below that directory.

Generally, if you can use the pre-packaged versions of software available in your Linux distribution your life will be easier.  For example, if you were to install the RedHat `openldap-servers` package, you would have a default configuration that would allow `slapd` to start and run correctly.

Comment: Thanks, `slapd -d none` helped finally debugging. Basically it wasn't able to create the `.pid` file. This was the error `51ff549f unable to open pid file "/usr/local/var/run/openldap/slapd.pid": 2 (No such file or directory)`. Once i created the `/usr/local/var/run/openldap/` path, its started fine

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall. look through either the log output from the configure command, or type "configure --help" to see a list of directories that things are installed in by default. Most likely it populated files into /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/lib, and so forth, so you'll need to into those directories and remove the files by hand.

Comment: why -1 rep for this? If you install openldap from source, then this is the best way to make sure you remove all files associated with the package. This isn't rpm or yum.